# Way to ignore some object or mesh when snap is active in blender 2.8?

Tags: interface

Question about way to exclude some object (target) when snapping is active on face,
 on interface or python script.

Comment: The only way I can think of is hiding those object that you don't want to snap to

Comment: Is an idea, but for me is no a good way unfortunately